# Why is the special character escaped in the command line

Tags: centos, character-encoding

I have an AlmaLinux server, in which I struggle with some encoding issue.
For example, if I type this in the CLI:

```
mkdir asdfü
ls ./
```

I get
`'asdf'$'\303\274'`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your terminal is configured for input/output to be encoded in UTF-8, but your shell session is in a locale with a different charset, one where bytes 0303 and 0274 (octal), individually or in combination don't form a valid of if valid printable character. Most likely, that locale is `C`/`POSIX` (the default locale when not defined or defined improperly) and the charset is ASCII (aka ANSI_X3.4-1968) which doesn't define any character for bytes 0303 nor 0274 (any byte above 0177).

```
locale charmap
```

Will tell you what charset is used in the locale.

```
locale
```

Will show you the locale configuration.

You'll likely want to change at least `$LANG` to a locale where the charset is UTF-8 and matches your preferences.

```
locale -a
```

Will give you a list of available locales on the server.

Comment: After I exported `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, everything was fine.